# Sort results in NetSuite web service support case search?

Tags: web-services, sorting, search, web, netsuite

Is it possible to set search preferences in the web service call to sort the data that is returned?

I am using the SupportCaseSearch object to perform a web service search that returns back a customer's support cases to be displayed in our Customer portal. I need to do this by paging the results and only bringing back a page at a time, because pulling back all of the support cases at once takes entirely too long. By default, NetSuite returns the support case records in ascending order of internal id. So with paging, the first page contains the oldest support cases a customer has since these obviously have the lowest internal IDs. This is obviously unacceptable for our website since the customer is going to expect to see their most recent cases first.

Is there a way to do the search where records will be returned in descending order of internal IDs or most recent lastModifiedDate first?

Answer (score 1):

Create a saved search of Support Cases with the sort order fields set on the Results tab - in your case, dateCreated DESC.

Use SupportCaseSearchAdvanced to execute the saved search, dynamically applying a filter for the customer field.

The results will come back sorted properly.

Comment: Is it also possible to achieve this without a saved search? E.g. programmatically through their SOAP API?